# mounted smb through fstab slower than dolphin browsing over smb://

Tags: kde, samba

I have mounted a share using fstab, in order to access its files using any application; but it is really slow. Even dolphin is slow listing folder content and sometimes freezes.

```
//192.168.1.7/shared  /home/user/mnt/servidor7  cifs credentials=/etc/.smbcredentials,noperm,user,noatime 0 0
```

But if I browse it through smb:// I works perfectly.

Are there any special parameters to mount it faster?